# Vue $emit in Promise

Tags: javascript, vue.js, promise

I am handling an upload for images - based on a Promise. In the "then" - callback I want to $emit an event. I call it 'success'. My VueDevTools shows me an success event, but in the parent component the "linked" method is never called. Is it possible that this.$emit('success') does not work within Promises?

Example Code - Child component:

```
UsersAPI.updateAvatar(this.user.id, data, fileExt).then(res => {
  if (res) {
    Helpers.callToast(this, 'is-success', this.$root.$t('profile.avatar_upload'))
    this.$emit('success')
  }
})
```

Example Code - Parent Component

```
<Avatar @success="test" :user="user" />
```

The method "test" in parent component is NEVER called, but the event is called in the vue dev tools. If I emit the event before the Promise, I get the result I wish.

Can you may help me?
Kind regards

Comment: Using `$emit` within a Promise should work fine, so long as you get the `this` binding correct. It appears to be correct in the code provided and if it were wrong you'd see a console error about `$emit` not being a function. How are you ascertaining that `test` isn't being called? I suggest adding some console logging or a `debugger` statement in the child component to check exactly what's going on in there. My current feeling is that the problem does not lie within the code you've posted.

Comment: BTW, what is `this.$root.$t`? there's a typo mistake I think, it should be `this.$root.$emit` isn't it?

Comment: Also, can you show us `Helpers.callToast` what's in here?

Answer (score 8):

In my case, the child component was **removed from the parent using "v-if" directive** when an API request was initialized.

Then, when my request finished, the child component emitted an event correctly, but in this moment the child wasn't rendered in the parent component's DOM, so the parent couldn't listen to that event.

Comment: This was exactly my problem. Thank you for your comment.

Comment: This is so obvious now you've pointed it out despite me spending countless hours trying to understand why my emit before a promise works but the one after never fires! Thank you so much for sharing the solution.

Answer (score 1):

I think it was because of the 'this' binding.

You need to bind the `this` of Vue component instance into the callback function.

```
const callbackFn = function(res) {
  if (res) {
    Helpers.callToast(this, 'is-success', this.$root.$t('profile.avatar_upload'))
    this.$emit('success')
  }
}.bind(this);

UsersAPI.updateAvatar(this.user.id, data, fileExt).then(callbackFn)
```

or you could simply create a new variable to save your Vue instance, then refer your callback function to use it.

```
const self = this;
UsersAPI.updateAvatar(this.user.id, data, fileExt).then(res => {
  if (res) {
    Helpers.callToast(this, 'is-success', self.$root.$t('profile.avatar_upload'))
    self.$emit('success')
  }
})
```

Comment: I already tried this and it doesnt work. I show you some more code: https://pastebin.com/jEEtsJwh

Comment: can you please comment out this line

`Helpers.callToast(this, 'is-success', this.$root.$t('profile.avatar_upload'))`

and try again?
i'm wondering if there is an issue on it

Comment: I did comment out Helpers.callToast line, but nothing changed...it has no impact